# Trigger build on commit does not work as expected

Tags: svn, jenkins

I had setup a post-commit hook to trigger build in Jenkins automatically on commit. It was working fine.I doubt that it stopped working after this 
1) Jenkins - when "poll scm" option is checked ( without any schedule in it.. which is the way it should be), it shows a warning "no schedules so will never run"
2) SVN was constantly crashing when too many jobs in Jenkins got triggered with a post-commit hook. So we created a svn ro server which points to svn, to reduce the load on svn. Jenkins uses this svn ro server ( because it all it needs is just read for checkout). After this change, svn stopped crashing. But polling also stopped working. What we noticed is polling is working for some jobs and not working at all for some jobs.

Any help on what I should do to fix this issue is appreciated.

NOTE: To whoever gave a -1 for this question, please elaborate on why you did that. Do you need more information to answer this question? Help me so that I can post better questions next time!

Comment: Please be clear and consistent. State the problem. Describe your setup. With details. What have you changed? With details. What have you tried? With details. Consider sharing your job configuration file. If you cannot do that, remove sensitive things from it and then share it. Also describe your environment: operating system, memory, number of jobs. Do not assume we can see over your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a stab at this:

> 1) Jenkins - when "poll scm" option is checked ( without any schedule in it.. which is the way it should be), it shows a warning "no schedules so will never run"

This is wrong. When you configure a post-commit hook on SVN, the job **must** be configured to have "poll scm" option. You cannot configure it without any schedule. You have to provide at least *some* schedule. Something infrequent, like once a month.

Fix this first, and then see if your issue in #2 improves.

***Edit:***
After OP mentioned "No credentials to try"
Try entering the repo credentials here:
`http://JENKINS_URL/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you look at the svn plugin page, it said, just enabling "poll scm" without any schedule is fine. Jobs were triggered 100% just with this setting before. Now it is 75%. PArticularly, a job has source code from multiple repos and it does not get triggered. nohup.out shows "No creddential to try" error on "OnNotify"...

Comment: Here is the link to plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin and the quote "The configured polling can have any schedule (probably infrequent like monthly or yearly)." It does not say "no schedule". Also edited answer with link to credentials page

Comment: Added a schedule to check every 15 mins as a temp fix. Now the builds get triggered when there is a change. Thanks for yor help Slav.